# MySql Query for generating report

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table which is having three fields:

```
Id, Creation Time, Fuel Level
```

Every two minutes we are getting data and inserting to database.For generating a fuel credit/debit statement i want to get starting(Stating of the day) and ending(End of the Day) Fuel Level.Can anyone help to form a query to generate this report?

Search parameters will be date range.

Id=10;creation time =2019-02-15 16:32:59;Fuel Level =20

I created one sample schema here
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76dd5

Comment: give us an example with some data in it

Comment: Please try something yourself and show us the current code, current output and your expected output.. That will help us in finding the solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, for a query that provides the change in fuel for each vehicle for each day, you can use the following SQL:

```
SELECT trip_range.dt
     , trip_range.vehicle_id
     , st.fuel_content as start_fuel_content
     , en.fuel_content as end_fuel_content
     , en.fuel_content - st.fuel_content as fuel_change
  FROM (
SELECT tp.vehicle_id, DATE(tp.creation_time) dt
     , MIN(tp.creation_time) start_time
     , MAX(tp.creation_time) end_time
  FROM trip_parameters tp
 GROUP BY tp.vehicle_id, DATE(tp.creation_time)
) as trip_range
  JOIN trip_parameters st
    ON st.vehicle_id = trip_range.vehicle_id
       AND st.creation_time = trip_range.start_time
  JOIN trip_parameters en
    ON en.vehicle_id = trip_range.vehicle_id
       AND en.creation_time = trip_range.end_time
 WHERE trip_range.dt BETWEEN '2012-11-08' AND '2012-11-09'
```

If you want the Cumulative change in fuel across all vehicles for each day in the range, the following SQL should work:

```
SELECT dt, SUM(fuel_change) as fuel_change
  FROM (
SELECT trip_range.dt
     , en.fuel_content - st.fuel_content as fuel_change
  FROM (
SELECT tp.vehicle_id, DATE(tp.creation_time) dt
     , MIN(tp.creation_time) start_time
     , MAX(tp.creation_time) end_time
  FROM trip_parameters tp
 GROUP BY tp.vehicle_id, DATE(tp.creation_time)
) as trip_range
  JOIN trip_parameters st
    ON st.vehicle_id = trip_range.vehicle_id
       AND st.creation_time = trip_range.start_time
  JOIN trip_parameters en
    ON en.vehicle_id = trip_range.vehicle_id
       AND en.creation_time = trip_range.end_time
 WHERE trip_range.dt BETWEEN '2012-11-08' AND '2012-11-09'
) change_by_vehicle
 GROUP BY 1
```

Hope this helps!

john...

Comment: Please either provide more information, such as table schema, sample rows, and example output.  Alternatively, go to http://sqlfiddle.com/ and create the table with some sample data.  Then post the resulting URL for us to "fiddle" with.

Comment: i created query in sqlfiddle..below one is the link  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76dd5

Comment: Thanks.  The sqlfiddle helps explain many things.  I've updated my answer accordingly.  You can run both of the queries I provide in sqlfiddle.

Comment: thank u very much.query works like a charm.now problem that i am facing is execution time of this query is quite high(a few minutes).trip_parameters table contains more than 5 lac rows.i have one more doubt is any way to find refuel amount for a vehicle for each day.It is like if difference of fuel level between two rows for one vehicle is more than 2,then i will consider it as refuel and by subtracting those rows will get refuel quantity.One more thing is same day multiple refuel may happen.So i need total refuel amount for day(per vehicle).is it possible to handle using query?

Comment: I suggest you make modifications to the first query I provided to determine refueling per car per day given your new criteria.  As for speed, I suggest making an index on vehicle_id and creation_time, and moving the date filter criteria into the inner SELECT.  The query is likely to run slow due to the GROUP BY DATE(...) clause, but there is little to be done about that aside from creating another field to just hold 'date', and creating an index on that as well.

Comment: i didn't find a solution to get refuel amount...but i going to accept ur solution...thanks....

Answer (score 1):

Try below:

```
   SELECT Id, CreationTime, FuelLevel
   FROM MYTABLE
   WHERE DATE(CreationTime) = CURDATE();
```

This gets the date part of `CreationTime` and compares against current date, thus returns all records created today.

Answer (score 1):

here's a query that returns the output as:

```
DATE            FUEL_CONTENT_AT_START_OF_DAY    FUEL_CONTENT_AT_END_OF_DAY
Nov, 08 2012    4.6                             3.6
Nov, 09 2012    11.6                            5.6
```

**Query**

```
SELECT
    DATE( startofday.creation_time) AS date,
    startofday.fuel_content AS fuel_content_at_start_of_day,
    (SELECT fuel_content FROM trip_parameters WHERE trip_paramid = max(endofday.trip_paramid) ) AS fuel_content_at_end_of_day
FROM
    trip_parameters startofday
    INNER JOIN trip_parameters endofday ON ( DATE( endofday.creation_time ) = DATE( startofday.creation_time) )
WHERE
    DATE( startofday.creation_time) BETWEEN '2012-11-08'  AND '2012-11-09'
GROUP BY
    startofday.TRIP_PARAMID
HAVING
  min( endofday.trip_paramid ) = startofday.trip_paramid
```

I have update the same on SQLFiddle, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76dd5/67

The query works as

- Get a row

  - Get all corresponding rows on the same day
  - Get the minimum and maximum ID on the same day
- If the current row Id equals the minimum Id from the JOIN display it, else ignore

  - Use the maximum id in a sub-query to get the end of day fuel_content

Hope this helps

Comment: is it possible to do same thing using a hql query

Comment: Would be better to fire complex queries directly using RAW SQL. Using a ORM for such things can make it slower and harder to understand